# why my expo doesn't have open ios simulator option

Tags: react-native, expo

```
› Metro waiting on exp://192.168.31.119:19001
› Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)

› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web

› Press j │ open debugger
› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
```

Why my expo does not have `open IOS simulator` option ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a windows machine?  That option doesn't exist for windows.  If you want to run it on an IOS device you'll need to create a development build.

https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/